# How to prove the following result in functional analysis?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $X_k$ be its $k$ dimensional subspace, $T$ be bounded linear operator on $X$,  $P_k$ be orthogonal projector onto $X_k$. How to prove $${N(TP_k)}^{\bot} = X_k \cap (N(T)\cap X_k)^{\bot} $$

I only able to prove the following $${N(TP_k)}^{\bot} \subseteq (N(T)\cap X_k)^{\bot} $$ as $$(N(T)\cap X_k) \subseteq N(TP_k)$$ How to prove further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply that $P_k$ is an orthogonal projection, hence $N(P_k)^\perp=X_k$

In addition $N(P_k) \subset N(TP_k)$ hence $N(TP_k)^\perp \subset N(P_k)^\perp=X_k$. The latter inclusion follows since $P_k$ is the *orthogonal* projection onto $X_k$.

Let $x_k\in X_k$ with $x_k \in (N(T)\cap X_k)^\perp$. Let $y\in N(TP_k)$. Then
$$
\langle y,x_k \rangle
=
\langle P_ky,x_k \rangle =0
$$
as $P_ky$ is in $N(T)\cap X_k$.

Comment: How $
\langle y,x_k \rangle
=
\langle P_ky,x_k \rangle 
$?

Comment: Thats orthogonality: $P_kz \perp (I-P_k)z$.